# Expectation of a Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

The expectation of a Gamma distribution

$E[Y^k]=\frac{\beta^k \Gamma(\alpha +k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$

What happens when $\alpha =\frac{1}{2}$?

$E[y^{\frac{1}{2}}]=\frac{\beta^{\frac{1}{2}} ((\alpha -\frac{1}{2})!}{(\alpha-1)!}$

Then...?

Comment: You need to compute the gamma function for $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the value of $$E[y^{\frac{1}{2}}]=\frac{\beta^{\frac{1}{2}} ((\alpha -\frac{1}{2})!}{(\alpha-1)!}$$ It does not make any problem since $0!=1$ and $(-\frac 12)!=\sqrt{\pi }$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function)).

All of that makes for  $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ $$E[y^{\frac{1}{2}}]=\sqrt{\frac \beta \pi}$$

Around $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, the Taylor series is $$\frac{\left(\alpha -\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{(\alpha -1)!}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{\log (4)}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}\left(\alpha -\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{ \left(3 \log ^2(4)-\pi ^2\right)}{6
   \sqrt{\pi }}\left(\alpha -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(\alpha -\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right)$$